# Does Kinesis Client Library consumer support AT_TIMESTAMP as a starting position when using Dynamodb streams kinesis adapter

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis, amazon-dynamodb-streams, amazon-kcl

According to [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.KCLAdapter.html) Dynamodb streams and Kinesis data streams low-level APIs are similar, but they are not 100 percent identical.

I notice that [Dynamodb streams' GetShardIterator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_GetShardIterator.html#API_streams_GetShardIterator_RequestSyntax) is a bit different i.e it doesn’t support **AT_TIMESTAMP** as a shard iterator type.

So, I presume that the adapter implementation will limit KCL consumer functionalities, and doesn’t allow **AT_TIMESTAMP** starting position.

Is my reasoning correct? I don’t yet implement it. I prefer to look for another solution if this seems to be a blocking point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinesis Client Library consumer doesn't support AT_TIMESTAMP as a starting position when using Dynamodb streams kinesis adapter:

https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-streams-kinesis-adapter/blob/50750146b1ccc1d87793522780ca21b4e376b2e1/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/streamsadapter/model/GetShardIteratorRequestAdapter.java#L142